# Using users input with sphinx in Django

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

I am trying to use sphinx for my django project. What I am trying to de specifically is accepting user's input, saving them somewhere(I will eventually push) and displaying their input with sphinx. Users will be able to create their own document version, toc...etc, my form will actually tell them to do that and it will accept their input and interact with sphinx. I have not seen any help or doc on this

Comment: A bit unclear.. What do you mean "accepting user input"? What have you tried?

Comment: for example: I want a user to be able to post blogs, where blogs have versions, chapter, etc. Sphinx will display that

Answer (score 1):

In [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), users type the content, it is stored in the database, and it is then transformed to html using a filter (e.g. see [django markdown filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/markup/#id1)).

From what I understood, you want to do the same, but for sphinx.

The way I see this can be done:

1. Have a model (e.g. `content`) that stores the sphinx text in a [TextField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#textfield) (e.g. `body`)
2. Have a filter that consumes what the user wrote and transforms it into html (I call it `sphinx_to_html`)
3. Have a template with `{{content.body|sphinx_to_html}}`
4. Have a view that renders the template with the context `{"content": content}`

The important detail should be on the implementation of `sphinx_to_html`, since you could have to compile the user input against some other files stored in the server. This is highly dependent on what you want to do specifically.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have my textarea in WYSIWYG and it converts to HTML in db; The problem I am now facing is, I want sphinx to actually display that "body" that has been saved in HTML format from the textarea mentioned above. Thank you :)